# ASP.NET How to open a folder at server side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to open folder location from code behind

```
  Process prc = new Process();
                prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                prc.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\Shared\FolderName\test";
                prc.Start();
```

After that I got it I couldn't achieve by using Shell32 class or Process.Start  on server side as well as adding link to path cant be used because of the security problem so how can achieve this problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to give access rights or permission to the folder which is a threat to security..

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you won't be able to launch an external process in a web application (and with good reason!). I think you need to reconsider what it is you're trying to achieve... perhaps some more information will help us give you a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

A web application hosted on server can not access external file and folders on the system. This is due to security reasons. However if you want to access some specific folder, you need to create virtual directory and give path to that folder to the virtual directory. Now you can access that folder using virtual directory.

I worked on such scenario where I needed to upload file using one application (admin app) and needed to show on an other application (client app). So it works fine if you want to access outside resources.